# Turn ngons left after beveling into quads

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, topology, bevel

This is a cube, with an edge beveled:

[image]

I'm not sure how to deal with the 2 ngons left here. How can I make it all-quad topology while maintaining the shape? Manually cut them like this:

[image]

? But when there are a lot of segments it gets tedious quickly. Plus what if it's not a cube?

[image]

Is there a more general or automatic way to handle the ngons left by beveling?

Comment: First of all it depends on what you need the "clean" topology for... N-gons are not naturally always bad, for example looking at your screenshot at the top, this is very nice clean topology. If you maybe have shading issues on the n-gons when shading smooth, you could for example simply inset the n-gon faces slightly. The answer moonboots gave is a clean mesh, too - but as I said, it depends on what you need, because the tris in that topology are not good if you want to do loop cuts which only work with quads.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ok, I edited the title to "all quad". (I know it's okay to have non-quad faces in some cases.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want an all quad topology to replace a planar N-gon:

1. Inset the face (shortcut <kbd>i</kbd>)
2. Delete the newly created face (shortcut <kbd>x</kbd> and select 'faces')
3. Select the enclosing edge loop (shortcut <kbd>ALT</kbd> and select an edge
4. Grid fill (from the face menu)  You may have to adjust the grid in the last operations tab.

I don't recommend doing the last two steps.  Insetting the face is usually sufficient geometry to handle shading issues.

Here are images to go with the steps

1. [image: inset the face]
2. [image: delete the newly created face]
3. [image: select the enclosing edges]
4. [image: grid fill]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

[image]

You could even leave it the way it is, with ngons, it all depends on what you're supposed to do with this object actually.